# How to define a HEX color macro in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm learning `swift` now have some trouble to convert my #define to swift

```
#define HColorToRGB(rgbValue,alphaValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:alphaValue]
```

how would you convert the Obj-C define to Swift code?

thanks for reading Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func HColorToRGB(rgbValue: Int, alpha: Float) -> UIColor {
return UIColor(
    red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
    green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
    blue: CGFloat(rgbValue &0xFF) / 255.0,
    alpha: CGFloat(alpha)
)
}


yourView.backgroundColor = HColorToRGB("passyourValue","alphaValue")
```

Comment: http://www.swiftapple.in/making-rgb-color-in-xcode-swift-language/

Comment: Today morning I also faced the same issue after that  I did like this , have a nice day my friend

Comment: @MartinR my question includes question about how to change the alpha which is different

Comment: @Desmond - check the updated answer